# how to save radion buttons in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-2.4

My Class:

```
package com

class Cafe {

    String cafeteriasurvey


    static constraints = {

        cafeteriasurvey nullable:true
    }

}
```

& form.gsp:

```
<%@ page import="com.Cafe" %>


<style>


h1{

text-align:center;

Color:#680000;

}

h2{

text-align:center;

font-weight:normal;

}

p{

font-style:Arial;

background-color:#b2b2b2;

}

.wrapper{

text-align:center;

}

.save{

text-align:center;

}

</style>

<h1>Cafeteria Survey</h1><br>


<h2 style="Color:#87212e">Caterer:Abhiruchi Caterers</h2><br>


<p>1.How would you rate for overall 'Breakfast' food items?</p><br>


<g:radioGroup name="cafeteriasurvey"


              values="['Muslim', 'Hindu', 'Christian', 'Buddhist']"


              labels="['Muslim', 'Hindu', 'Christian', 'Buddhist']"


              value="${cafeInstance?.cafeteriasurvey}">


    <p>${it.label}: ${it.radio}</p>


</g:radioGroup>
```

Any solutions how to save radio button.

Comment: This is near enough not even a grails question. What would you use in html to post an item ? A form ? a form that has a submit URL so <g:form controller="something" action="someAction"> radioButton SUBMIT button then </g:form>. Please study some basic html stuff first before attempting a grails application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the name(params.cafeteriasurvey) in controller.
then create new object . 
and call object.save()
refer this
http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/radioGroup.html